# How can I open the path I set in Nextjs on the new tab?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
<Link to="/newpage">New Page </Link>
```

I have started a project with nextjs and I want to open the link on a new page when I click on the path I introduced with route. How can i do this?

Comment: If you're using Next.js you should use [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link), which does not have the `to` prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<Link to="/newpage" target="_blank">New Page </Link>
```

Comment: He said `in next.js`

Answer (score 2):

Add target attribute on a tag

```html
<Link href="/document/terms">
  <a target="_blank">Link</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

With next.js version `^13` it's simply as follows:

```
import Link from 'next/link'; // Don't forget this

<Link href='link-to-your-target' target='_blank'>Link Title</Link>
```